# How to let qt webengine call react compontent function

Tags: reactjs, qt, antd

I got a problem 
  The `RunJavaScript4` api can't call function , when i click a button bind a js function in a page render by react . The console log function `goOnPkg` is not defined

qt version 5.10

code in go file:

```
channel := webchannel.NewQWebChannel(nil)
channel.RegisterObject("pkgBridge", qmlBridge)
wv.Page().SetWebChannel2(channel)
qmlBridge := NewQmlBridge(nil)
qmlBridge.ConnectSendToGo(func(data string) string {
  ap.WebView.Page().RunJavaScript4(fmt.Sprintf("%s('%s')", funcName, data))
})
```

code in react compontent:

```
export  function go0nPkg(id) {
    console. log("golang can' t call this function successfully") ;
    console. log(id);
}

@Form.create()
class PkgDoPkgList extends React Component {
constructor(props) 
componentDidMount( ) {}
handlePkgBtnClick = (id, actionId, action) => {
let action_obj = { "action": action, "action_id": actionId};
let action_json = JSON.stringify(action_obj );

new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel)  {
    pkgBridge = channel.objects.pkgBridge;
    window.bridge = pkgBridge;
    window.bridge.sendToGo(action_json);
}
render() {}
export default PkgDoPkgList;
```

golang can't call function in react compontent successfully. -_-!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aha, i solved this problem .

1. in js file, we should export React Class instance to window.

```
import xxx;

//...

window.updateValue = function(url) {
    alert("call ok !");
    // if(window.callback != undefined) {
    //    window.callback.updateValue(url);
    // }
};

window.setCallback = function(callback) {
    window.callback = callback;
}

//...

export default class MyFeedback extends React.Component {

   //...
   // key step
   //  in react life cycle `componentWillMount` set `this` :
   componentWillMount() {
         window.setCallback(this);
   }

  //...

}
```

2. in go file, we call function like this :

```
ap.WebView.Page().RunJavaScript4("window.updateValue('hello')")
```

after run project .  i see  alert `call ok!` .

[Refer to the link : https://blog.csdn.net/ZHOUYONGXYZ/article/details/82760929](https://blog.csdn.net/ZHOUYONGXYZ/article/details/82760929)